# How does python interpreter decides when to invokes the __set__ and __get__ methods and when not to?

Tags: python

Suppose we define the following python descriptor

```
class FooDescriptor():
    def __init__(self, name='foo', initval='initval'):
        self.name = name
        self.val = initval

    def __get__(self, instance, cls):
        print("invoke get {} in instance {} in class {}".format(self.name, instance, cls))
        return self.val

    def __set__(self, instance, val):
        print("invoke set {} in instance {}".format(self.name, instance))
        self.val = val
```

Now if we define the class `Foo` to have a class attribute of type `FooDescriptor` and the instance attribute of the same type:

```
class Foo():
    cdescr = FooDescriptor(name='class attribute descr', initval=1)
    def __init__(self):
        self.idescr = FooDescriptor(name='instance attribute descr', initval=2)
```

We get the desired behaviour for the class descriptor:

```
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> foo.cdescr
invoke get class attribute descr in instance <__main__.Foo object at 0x10189ecc0> in class <class '__main__.Foo'>
1
>>> foo.cdescr = 100
invoke set class attribute descr in instance <__main__.Foo object at 0x10189ecc0>
>>> foo.cdescr
invoke get class attribute descr in instance <__main__.Foo object at 0x10189ecc0> in class <class '__main__.Foo'>
100
```

However for the instance attribute `idescr`, the descriptor object's `__set__` and `__get__` methods do not get invoked when attribute is accessed or set:

```
>>> foo.idescr
<__main__.FooDescriptor object at 0x10189ecf8>
>>> foo.idescr = 120
>>> foo.idescr
120
>>> type(foo.idescr)
<class 'int'>
```

Any answer for better understanding the scope of the descriptors and how python decides to invoke their `__set__` and `__get__` when attribute protocal `.` is seen would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The descriptor protocol won't work on instance attributes. Descriptors are ment to be members of the *class* object, not the instance object

Answer (score 1):

That's because descriptors are used when looking up an attribute on the class of an instance. If it's an instance attribute it won't bother with the descriptor protocol.

A good ressource for this kind of question is ionel's blog about metaclasses, which contains this image which also shows when descriptors are used:

[image]

(image copied from [here](https://blog.ionelmc.ro/2015/02/09/understanding-python-metaclasses/#object-attribute-lookup))

Because `cdescr` is in the `class.__dict__` and has `__get__` and `__set__` it will return what the descriptors `__get__` returns. However because `idescr` is not in the `class.__dict__` it will simply return what is stored in the `instance.__dict__`.